# No response from PHP when using jQuery + AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Been pulling my hair out with this one, I've got no idea why I'm not getting any response from my PHP file. The AJAX request is running the success function but with nothing coming back from PHP.

JS

```
jQuery('#submit').on('click', function(e){
    var data = {
            email: jQuery('#email').val(),
            string: jQuery('#string').val(),
        };

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-content/themes/suttons/parts/tankLookup.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            console.log("yes");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("no");
        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $string = $_REQUEST['string'];

    $return = array();

    array_push($return, $email);
    array_push($return, $string);

    echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

I've tried simpler code as well, down to just the basics in the PHP file and still a success but an empty response.

```
<?php
    echo "true";
?>
```

Comment: `return = array();` ...typo, should be `$return` presumably. That'll cause a syntax error.

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's Network tool to see what's happening to your request? Check the status code it returns with, and check the raw output (you can click on the request and look at the Response tab to see exactly what output the server sent back, if any).

Comment: P.S. If you're using wordpress you should likely use their ajax framework rather than having your own random script. [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+ajax)

Comment: @ADyson Fair enough on that one, defo a typo on my part. Still not returning anything tho. Response tab in the inspector claims "This request has no response data available."

Comment: What's the HTTP status code of the response?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's Console after you try to run this?

Comment: Gives a response of 200 OK, only things in the console are the output from the two console.log functions, one with "yes" and one totally blank

Comment: I don't know wordpress but at a guess I'd assume something in the wordpress setup intercepts the request and it doesn't actually reach your script. You could test that by also having the PHP script write something to a file and seeing if that happens when you run the ajax code. Maybe a htaccess rule blocks/rewrites it, or some other handler? As I said above, I do know wordpress has its own framework for making ajax requests and you should probably follow that to get the best results.

Comment: Do you see errors in the error log?